# Is there something wrong with this rwLock implementation?

Tags: c++, mutex, rwlock

My program is deadlocking, and I have no idea why, given that it won't do it when I run it in a debugger, so my first suspect is my rwLock, I wrote my own version because I only wanted to use standard libraries--I don't think a rwLock is included until C++17--and this isn't the sort of thing I normally do.

```
class RwLock
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_lock;
    std::condition_variable condition;

    int  reading_threads;
    bool writing_threads;

public:
    RwLock();
    ~RwLock();

    void read_lock();
    void read_unlock();

    void write_lock();
    void write_unlock();
};


RwLock::RwLock() :
    mutex(),
    unique_lock(mutex, std::defer_lock),
    condition(),
    reading_threads(0),
    writing_threads(false)
{
}

RwLock::~RwLock()
{
    //TODO: find something smarter to do here.
    write_lock();
}

void RwLock::read_lock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();

    while(writing_threads)
    {
        condition.wait(unique_lock);
    }

    ++reading_threads;
    unique_lock.unlock();
}

void RwLock::read_unlock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();

    if(--reading_threads == 0)
    {
        condition.notify_all();
    }

    unique_lock.unlock();
}

void RwLock::write_lock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();

    while(writing_threads)
    {
        condition.wait(unique_lock);
    }

    writing_threads = 1;

    while(reading_threads)
    {
        condition.notify_all();
    }

    unique_lock.unlock();
}

void RwLock::write_unlock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();
    writing_threads = 0;
    condition.notify_all();
    unique_lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: `while(reading_threads) { condition.notify_all(); }` That'll wait forever if there's any reader. You never unlock the lock and thus never give the reader a chance to decrement `reading_threads`. Looks like a copy/paste error to me - I bet you meant to `condition.wait` here, not `notify_all`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I had copied this from another website and modified it, so yeah it was.  I had a feeling that line was the problem, but neither situation makes a ton of sense to me honestly.

Comment: `shared_timed_mutex` exists in C++14

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_timed_mutex` exists prior to C++17: in C++14.

Use it instead, it will have fewer bugs and be faster almost certainly.

C++17 introduces `shared_mutex` which can be even faster.   But I strongly doubt your ability to implement a faster shared rwlock than `shared_timed_mutex` using C++ standard primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good except for two issues in this code:

```
void RwLock::write_lock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();

    while(writing_threads)
    {
        condition.wait(unique_lock);
    }

    writing_threads = 1;

    while(reading_threads)
    {
        condition.notify_all();
    }

    unique_lock.unlock();
}
```

First, you increment `writing_threads` too late. A reader could sneak in. It's possible that you don't mind or even want this, but typically this is undesired.

Second, your notify in the last `while` loop should be a `wait`. Putting it together, we get:

```
void RwLock::write_lock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();

    ++writing_threads;

    while((writing_threads > 1) || (reading_threads > 0))
    {
        condition.wait(unique_lock);
    }

    unique_lock.unlock();
}

void RwLock::write_unlock()
{
    unique_lock.lock();
    --writing_threads; // note change here
    condition.notify_all();
    unique_lock.unlock();
}
```

This is actually a bit simpler, which is nice.